How can I run a react-native app in development mode without connection to metro server
I have just upgraded from react 0.72.x to 0.75.3 and the behaviour when building the development app has changed.
Previously, I could build a development version (using npm run android), and the app would be installed in development mode, showing errors/warnings etc whenever i used it, it didn't need to be connected to metro.
I have just upgraded to 0.75.3 and now, if I try and use the app when not connected to the computer, it doesn't work and throws up a

Could not connect to development server

error screen. I checked all the files that got modified during the upgrade from 0.72 to 0.75 and can't find anything that appears to have changed a setting like this. Maybe flipper??
I know I can do a production build to run the app, however that is not ideal (the debugging screens are useful to find bugs while I'm using it on the day to day, plus it's time consuming).
So, is it possible to use it like before, and use a development app without metro?
